# Adding Data items to exception but not calling throw ex

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

I have extended NLog to log all items in the Exception.Data collection.  So, when I catch an SqlException, in my data access code, I like to add a few items to the Exception.Data dictionary to provide better logging.  I don't always want to log from within the catch, but instead, let the exception bubble up and be handled later.  So I write something like this:

```
Try
   ...
Catch exception As Exception
   exception.Data.Add("SP", StoreProcedureNameCost)
   exception.Data.Add("Connection", myConnection.ConnectionString)
   Throw
End Try
```

Does calling just `Throw` instead of `Throw exception` still have have all of my added Data items?

Comment: That would be quite easy to try in your compiler...

Comment: Downvoter, what was the downvote for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It will preserve the changes made to Data property. The fundamental difference between `throw` and `throw ex` is that the stack trace does not change with calling `throw` whereas it gets changed with `throw ex`.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try myself and it works like I hoped.  Just calling throw DOES preserve new data added to the exception:

```
Try
   Try
      Throw New NotImplementedException("Hi")
   Catch ex As Exception
      ex.Data.Add("Here", "It is there")
      Throw
   End Try
Catch ex As Exception
   Dim msg As String = ex.Data("Here").ToString()
   Response.Write(msg)
End Try
```

It worked and spit out "It is there".